# Extract specific block from xml file

Tags: bash, xml-parsing

```
<ruleId>1412</ruleId>

<myCount>2</myCount>
<hisCount>0</hisCount>
<totalCount>2</totalCount>
<ruleId>109942</ruleId>

<myCount>2</myCount>
<hisCount>2785</hisCount>
<totalCount>0</totalCount>
<ruleId>109367</ruleId>

<myCount>1</myCount>
<hisCount>567</hisCount>
<totalCount>0</totalCount>
<ruleId>1412</ruleId>

<myCount>2</myCount>
<hisCount>4</hisCount>
<totalCount>6</totalCount>
```

I want to extract value of `myCount`, `hisCount` and `totalCount` where `ruleId = 1412`

---

Here the rule #1412 appears twice my expected output will be like this:

```
mycount-SUM = 2+2 = 4

hisCount-SUM = 0+4 = 4

totalCount-SUM = 2+6 = 8

RuleID  mycount-SUM  hisCount-SUM  totalCount-SUM

1412    4            4             8
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete `XML` with root nodes? It will be easy that way to parse using `XML` parsers

Comment: a valid xml requires `root` element

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: So the actual xml is not like this. I extracted the ruleIds from it and counted which one is the most frequent using grep awk and sort commands. But that doesn't gives me sum of different counts for that particular ruleId

Comment: @Manoj: `grep`, `awk` are not the best ways to do this. When you said `xml-parsing`, you need to work with more syntax aware tools like `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet` which need the complete `XML` from root node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complex ***bash*** + [***xmlstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) solution:

A valid xml structure would look like below (for ex. `rules.xml`):

```
<rules>
<ruleId>1412</ruleId>

<myCount>2</myCount>
<hisCount>0</hisCount>
<totalCount>2</totalCount>
<ruleId>109942</ruleId>

<myCount>2</myCount>
<hisCount>2785</hisCount>
<totalCount>0</totalCount>
<ruleId>109367</ruleId>

<myCount>1</myCount>
<hisCount>567</hisCount>
<totalCount>0</totalCount>
<ruleId>1412</ruleId>

<myCount>2</myCount>
<hisCount>4</hisCount>
<totalCount>6</totalCount>
</rules>
```

---

***rule_counts.sh*** script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ruleId=$2

getSum () {
    echo $(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "sum(//ruleId[text()=$2]/following-sibling::$3[1])" "$1")
}

mySum=$(getSum $1 $ruleId "myCount")
hisSum=$(getSum $1 $ruleId "hisCount")
totalSum=$(getSum $1 $ruleId "totalCount")

printf "%-6s\t%-11s\t%-12s\t%-14s\n" "RuleID" "mycount-SUM" "hisCount-SUM" "totalCount-SUM" 
printf "%-6s\t%-11s\t%-12s\t%-14s\n" "$ruleId" "$mySum" "$hisSum" "$totalSum"
```

***Usage***:

```
bash rule_counts.sh rules.xml 1412
```

signature: `<shell script> <xml file> <ruleId node value>` (all mandatory)

---

The output:

```
RuleID  mycount-SUM hisCount-SUM    totalCount-SUM
1412    4           4               8
```

---

***Explanation***:

`ruleId=$2` - points to the second command line argument passed to shell script

`"sum(//ruleId[text()=$2]/following-sibling::$3[1])"` - xpath expression, returns the [***sum***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-sum) for each passed node in the argument node-set

for `myCount` node it will be `"sum(//ruleId[text()=1412]/following-sibling::myCount[1])"`

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-sum

the `following-sibling` axis contains all the following siblings of the context node